# Render separate PDFs for every chapter with arara

Tags: arara

I have a `memoir` document which contains my PhD thesis.
I would like to automatically create a separate PDF for every chapter, as well as a master PDF.
I found [this](https://gitlab.cs.dartmouth.edu/irhs/dartmouth-thesis-template/blob/2c5b2aa314c30d00662190bf3d659ec7d9240926/makechapters.yaml) `arara` rule, which seems to do exactly what I want.
However, the format is not compatible with `arara` 4.0.
The main issue seems to be that it was possible to use `items` as an argument, which would then automatically be iterated (?).
`arara` 4.0 does not accept this `items` argument.
I was able to define a new argument `chapters`, and to iterate through it.
I don't know how to compile a new PDF when within the MVEL (?) environment though.

Here is my code so far.
It first compiles the whole document, and then iterates over `chapters`, printing their names (line 9).
The goal would be to instead run something like the following command on line 9.

`- <arara> @{engine} "\includeonly{@{chapter}}\input{@{chapter}}"`

```
!config
identifier: makechapters
name: MakeChapters
commands:
- command: <arara> @{ isTrue( compileAll, engine.concat(' ').concat(file) )}
- command: >
    @{
      foreach (chapter : chapters) {
        System.out.println(chapter)
      }
    }
arguments:
- identifier: engine
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.engine}
  default: xelatex
- identifier: compileAll
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.compileAll}
  default: true
- identifier: chapters
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.chapters}
  default: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be a nice start for our rule:

```
!config
identifier: makechapters
name: MakeChapters
commands:
- name: Making chapters
  command: >
    @{
        if (compile == 'all') {
            return getCommand(engine, file);
        }
        else {
            entries = [];
            base = getBasename(file);
            foreach (chapter: chapters) {
                entries.add(getCommand(engine, '\\includeonly{' + chapter +
                                               '}\\input{' + base + '}'));
            }
            return entries;
        }
    }
arguments:
- identifier: engine
  flag: >
    @{
        if ([ 'pdflatex', 'latex', 'xelatex',
              'lualatex' ].contains(parameters.engine)) {
            return parameters.engine;
        }
        else {
            throwError('The provided engine is not valid');
        }
    }
  default: xelatex
- identifier: compile
  flag: >
    @{
        if ([ 'all', 'chapters' ].contains(parameters.compile)) {
            return parameters.compile;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting "all" or "chapters".');
        }
    }
  default: 'all'
- identifier: chapters
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.chapters)) {
            return parameters.chapters;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of chapters.');
        }
    }
```

Let's break it down:

```
!config
identifier: makechapters
name: MakeChapters
```

These are the headers, nothing new here. `:)`

```
commands:
```

Now we are creating the commands (actually, just one, as we will see in a minute).

```
- name: Making chapters
  command: >
    @{
```

Here it goes, the heart of our rule.

```
        if (compile == 'all') {
            return getCommand(engine, file);
        }
```

I decided to make `compile` a string variable instead of a boolean one, so we could specify two values for it: `all`, in case we want to compile the document, or `chapters`, in case we want to compile each chapter.

```
        else {
```

Now we are inside the `else` branch, i.e, we will compile each chapter individually.

```
            entries = [];
            base = getBasename(file);
```

The `entries` variable will hold a list of commands, each one for a chapter, and the `base` variable holds the basename of the current `file` reference.

```
            foreach (chapter: chapters) {
                entries.add(getCommand(engine, '\\includeonly{' + chapter +
                                               '}\\input{' + base + '}'));
            }
```

Note that `chapters` holds a list of strings, so we can iterate the values and, for each one, we create a corresponding command with the structure you provided before (note that I had to escape the backslash) and add to the list.

```
            return entries;
        }
    }
```

Now we simply return the list of commands and let `arara` do the rest.

Time to check the arguments:

```
arguments:
```

Let's go!

```
- identifier: engine
  flag: >
    @{
        if ([ 'pdflatex', 'latex', 'xelatex',
              'lualatex' ].contains(parameters.engine)) {
            return parameters.engine;
        }
        else {
            throwError('The provided engine is not valid');
        }
    }
  default: xelatex
```

Nothing new here, I just added a check to ensure the value is within a list of valid engine names.

```
- identifier: compile
  flag: >
    @{
        if ([ 'all', 'chapters' ].contains(parameters.compile)) {
            return parameters.compile;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting "all" or "chapters".');
        }
    }
  default: 'all'
```

Same idea of the previous argument, I check whether `compile`, when specified, contains either `all` or `chapters`.

```
- identifier: chapters
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.chapters)) {
            return parameters.chapters;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of chapters.');
        }
    }
```

And at last, but not least, we ensure `chapters` is an actual list. `:)`

Let's see this rule in action (via `--dry-run`).

Header:

```
% arara: makechapters: { chapters: [ foo, bar ], compile: 'chapters' }
```

Output:

```
[DR] (MakeChapters) Making chapters
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: No authors provided
About to run: [ xelatex, \includeonly{foo}\input{foo} ]

[DR] (MakeChapters) Making chapters
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: No authors provided
About to run: [ xelatex, \includeonly{bar}\input{bar} ]
```

Header:

```
% arara: makechapters: { engine: pdflatex }
```

Output:

```
[DR] (MakeChapters) Making chapters
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Authors: No authors provided
About to run: [ pdflatex, test.tex ]
```

Hope it helps. `:)` I am not sure about the trick of compiling each chapter individually (never seen it before, to be honest), but that's the idea. Perhaps it's advisable to also set up `-jobname` for the underlying engine?

Comment: Thank you!

I am getting `Missing \begin{document}.`, because on line 15, we first have `\includeonly{chapter}` and then `\input{chapter`; the second one should actually be `input{file}`, at least when I look at the [3.0 compatible version](https://gitlab.cs.dartmouth.edu/irhs/dartmouth-thesis-template/blob/2c5b2aa314c30d00662190bf3d659ec7d9240926/makechapters.yaml). Changing that fixes it.

However, now all the PDF files have the main file's name, i.e. it is overwritten every time. When I tried to add  "-jobname=" + chapter to the command, I get a stack overlow with the chapter`.aux`

Comment: @folran what happens if you add `-jobname=` right after the `engine`? Try replacing the second `getCommand(engine, ...` by `getCommand(engine, '-jobname=' + chapter, ...` and see if it works.

Comment: @folran we can also rename the resulting PDF before processing the next one. `:)` Which operating system do you use?

Comment: Yeah I also figured that changing the filename would be a good idea. That fixed the problem.

Now, next issue: how do I first run `biber` on the main file?

Comment: Update: got it! Will post my complete solution when I have time.

Comment: Alright, so the relevant changes I had to make resulted in this:

```
foreach (chapter: chapters) {
                entries.add(getCommand(engine, "-jobname=tmpCMH", '\\includeonly{content/' + chapter +
                                               '}\\input{' + file + '}'));
                entries.add(getCommand("mv", "tmpCMH.pdf", chapter + ".pdf"))
            }
```

`\input` has to take the main file as an argument, and  `-jobname` is set to a temporary value; the resulting PDF is then renamed with `mv`. You will have to change the last part when using windows.